# Angular ui directives as attribute

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible for me to use  angular ui directives as attributes or class instead of elements??

eg:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li class="accordion-group">
        my content
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is covered in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: @ivarni can you just send me the link??

Comment: I just did. "documentation" in my comment is clickable.

Comment: Actually the answer is in the code. The directives are declared as restrict 'EA', so that's yes to attribute, no to class... https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js

Comment: @ivarni I know it works well enough for custom directives but i am not sure if angular-ui directives are written with restrict as 'EAC'

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @AnthonyChu tanx for the link guess i will try myself now

Comment: I suppose since angular-ui restricts with 'EA' you would have to either make a request for them to use 'EAC' or maintain your own fork.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can do :) .

An Angular directive comes in four flavors in terms of appearance.

- A new HTML element (`<date-picker></date>`).
- An attribute on an element (`<input type="text" date-picker/>`).
- As a class (`<input  type="text" class="date-picker"/>`).
- As comment  (`<!--directive:date-picker-->`).

.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
  };
});
```

.

- `restrict` – This provides a way to specify how a directive should be used in HTML (remember a directive can appear in four ways). In this case we have set it to 'AE'. So, the directive can be used as a new HTML element or an attribute. To allow this directive to be used as a class we can set restrict to 'AEC'.
- `template` – This specifies the HTML markup that will be produced when the directive is compiled and linked by Angular. This does not have to be a simple string. The template can be complex, often involving other directives, expressions ({{ }}), etc. In most cases you want to use templateUrl instead of template. So, ideally you should place the template in a separate HTML file and make templateUrl point to it.
- `replace` – This specifies if the generated template will replace the HTML element on which the directive is attached. In our case we have used the directive as , and replace is set to true. So, after the directive is compiled, the produced output template replaces . The final output is `<h3>Hello World!!</h3>`. If you set replace to false, the default, the output template will be inserted into the element on which the directive is invoked.

check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GKI339z2VDdZTOE2bGFP)

for more info visit [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: I know it works well enough for custom directives but i was not sure if angular-ui directives are written with restrict as 'EAC'